# Privileged file/directory picker for webexetnsions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, input-type-file

Is there any webextensions way to get a file picker which can get a file path and/or accept a directory as an argument? (like `nsiFilePicker` had previously)

Obviously this is for a native messaging add-on...

(And I'd prefer a built-in browser solution (or library) rather than having to implement a file picker HTML app myself communicating back and forth with Node for this purpose...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `<input type="file">` element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: While contents are normally what people want, the file input won't provide the *path* or optionally allow selection of a directory...